# prove that $J=\{f(x) \in Q[x]:f(\sqrt{2})=0)\}$ is a maximal ideal of $Q[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Please, help me to solve this problem:

"If $\mathbb Q$$[\sqrt{2}]=\{f(\sqrt{2}):f(x) \in Q[x]\}$, prove that $J=\{f(x) \in Q[x]:f(\sqrt{2})=0)\}$ is a maximal ideal of $Q[x]$".

Obs.: $Q[x]$ is the set of all polinoms with rational coeficients.

My strategy is as follows:

It is easy to prove that $Q[\sqrt{2}]$ equals $\{x+y\sqrt{2}:x,y \in Q\}$. I want to prove that $I \supset J \rightarrow I=J$ or $I=Q[x]$. Now I supose $f(x) \in I$ such that $f(x) \notin J$. Then $I \neq J$ and $f(\sqrt{2}) \neq 0$, i.e, there exists $x,y \in Q$ such that $x+y\sqrt{2}=b \neq 0$. Since $Q$ is a field, there exists $b^{-1}$ such that $b.b^{-1}=1$. Then $x.b^{-1}+y.b^{-1}\sqrt{2} = 1$. It proves that $1 \in Q[\sqrt{2}]$, but I'd like to get the result that $1 \in I$. Does anyone has a suggestion? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint* Show that $\Bbb Q[\sqrt 2]=\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)$, i.e. your quotient is a field. Alternatively, $x^2-2$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Hello, Pedro. Ok, but I am trying to prove directly.

Comment: Prove that $J=(X^2-2)$, and use that $X^2-2$ is irreducible, @Walter.